# Meteor 1.3 import module errors

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6, importerror

I have a project with the following structure :

```
Project : 
   -client
        -layouts
          -mainlayouts.jsx
        -components
          -homepage.jxs
   -lib
        -routes.jsx
```

So in my routes.jsx I want to import module from mainlayouts and hompepage, and this is what I did:

```
import {MainLayout} from '../client/layouts/mainlayouts.jsx';
import HomePage from '../client/templates/homepage.jxs';
```

But I got this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../client/layouts/mainlayouts.jsx'
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an "absolute" path instead :

```
/client/layouts/mainlayouts.jsx
```

By "absolute", I mean relative to your meteor project root, which is a meteor specific feature of ES2015 module imports.

Comment: still got the error `Error: Cannot find module '/client/layouts/mainlayouts.jsx'`